# What did Westinghouse use for power to drive Tesla's generators during the 1892 World's Fair

Tags: electricity

I did manage to find technical drawings of the World's fair after considerable searching but probably I am not savvy enough to find the right items. In one of the drawings it does show what appears to be almost a geothermal structure of some type.  Other drawings clearly show the alternating current generation room , and in fact that was one of the main attractions at the fair, but I cannot make out where the drive shaft is going to make it spin. Does anyone happen to be a late 1800 historian of the "alternating current wars" will probably know off the top of his head.  Thank you

Comment: I once tried to find the answer to this question but gave up.  My guess though it that the generators were steam powered.  However, since the direct result of Westinghouse/Tesla success at the Chicago World's Fair was winning the power plant project at Niagara Falls, it could have been maybe Hydro but I have no idea where the Hydro source would have been. I am confident that the energy source was not Nuclear and Not Gas-Turbine (aka Jet engine).

Comment: The sketch I saw looked like there was a large pipe going under the ground...possibly hydraulic as you suggest but it appears to be a unique situation and that is way I was trying to find out how it was actually done. very puzzling to me....but thank you for trying./...by the way you can google on the 1982 World's fair and look at the schematics yourself...they are interesting but hard to figure out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The  [Tesla Society](http://www.teslasociety.com/columbia_expo.htm) has a photo of a "Allis-Corliss Engine."
Wikipedia identifies this as a large steam-powered engine.

And over at [vintagemachinery.org](http://wiki.vintagemachinery.org/Steam-Engines-at-the-World-s-Fair-Parts-1-2.ashx),  it is stated explicitly that

> The duty of the World's Fair [Corliss] engine will, however, be of a different
>   nature from that of the Corliss engine at the Centennial, which
>   transmitted its power to the main jack shaft. The Allis engine is
>   belted by two belts made by the Page Belting Company, of Concord, N.
>   H., to two Westinghouse dynamos, each of a capacity of 10,000
>   incandescent light. The speed necessary for these machines to produce
>   20,000 light of sixteen candle-power is 200 revolutions. The
>   illustration shows only one belt, but when completed the second belt
>   will be directly over the f1rst connected to the second dynamo
>   immediately beyond. The fly-wheel is thirty feet in diameter, and at
>   sixty revolutions, will have a periphery speed of over 5500 feet per
>   minute. The face of the wheel is seventy-six inches, not as large as
>   many others the Allis Company have built, but in construction it is
>   probably stronger than any of its size ever made. It has twelve arms
>   and the rim is made up of the same number of segments. It weighs
>   complete 135,900 pounds, the rim itself weighing 88,000 pounds.

I'd add in passing that, having lived on Chicago's South Side only a few blocks from the Midway,  I can attest there's no chance of a Hydro-powered source anywhere near there :-)

Comment: I have never lived in Chicago but been there lots of times and I never saw evidence of a nice Hydro source.  I live in Washington state and the Columbia river has a zillion (or a little less) Hydro generating stations on it and I can usually recognize those kind of plants.